# Dynamic instance attributes

Tags: python, class, attributes

Say i have a class:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self,d):
        self.d=d

d={'a':1,'b':2}

inst=Foo(d)

inst.d
Out[315]: {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Is there a way to dyamically create n attributes where each attribute would be a dict key, so `inst.a` would return `1` and so on.

Comment: Yes, but you wouldn't be able to use them because `inst.0` is illegal syntax.

Comment: Yes, but why would you do that instead of accessing items by index, either straight from the list, or by overriding [`__getitem__` and friends](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types).

Comment: @ delnan -- it's just an example, not a very practical solution, I would just like to learn how to dynamically create attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `setattr()`:

```
>>> class foo(object):
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.d = d
        for x in self.d:
            setattr(self, x, self.d[x])


>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> l = foo(d)
>>> l.d
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> l.a
1
>>> l.b
2
>>>
```

Comment: @root yes, just move the for-loop inside the `__init__()`.see the edited solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, attributes):
        self.__dict__.update(attributes)
```

That would do it.

```
>>>foo = Foo({'a': 42, 'b': 999})
>>>foo.a
42
>>>foo.b
999
```

You can also use the `setattr` built-in method:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, attributes):
        for attr, value in attributes.iteritems():
            setattr(self, attr, value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution even more outlandish than the one offered by pythonm:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.__dict__ = d
```

Instead of using `inst.d`, use `inst.__dict__` directly. An added benefit is that new keys added to `d` automatically become attributes. That's as dynamic as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwdargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwdargs)

d = {'a':1,'b':2}

foo = Foo(**d)
foo2 = Foo(a=1, b=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `__getattr__`.

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, d):
        self.d = d

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self.d[name]
```